# Part of domain not being plotted in Show

Tags: plotting, functions

I am exploring Euler's product formula for the Riemann `Zeta` function but I have come across a problem plotting functions with various terms of accuracy. My code is as follows:

```
Show[Plot[Zeta[x], {x, -1, 4}, PlotRange -> {-4, 8}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness -> .005}],
    Table[Plot[Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, i}], {x, -1, 10}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Black}, PlotPoints -> 1000], {i, 1, 2}]
]
```

This produces the following image.

[image: 1 and 2 terms of accuracy]

So the zeta function is in red and I am using a table to produce the product approximations, which are in black. My question is why does the product not get plotted for a lot of the domain I specified? Obviously it won't be defined at $x = 0$, but everywhere else in my domain should be plotted, yes?

I thought this was a problem with using a table maybe, but explicitly plotting

```
1/(1-1/2^x)
```

gave the same problem where it ignored a lot of the domain. Any help?

Comment: The function `Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, 2}],` rises too fast near 0: see `LogPlot[Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, 2}], {x, -1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, PlotPoints -> 1000,  PlotRange -> All]` or  `LogPlot[Log@Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, 2}], {x, -1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, PlotPoints -> 1000,  PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did what you did in your second comment and just gave an explicit PlotRange to the table functions which fixed it. In regards to your first, the table functions should be growing slower than the zeta functions so that was fine. No idea why it seems to be giving arbitrary PlotRanges to my table functions, but that works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Show[Plot[Zeta[x], {x, -1, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {-4, 8}}, 
  Exclusions -> {1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness -> .005}], 
 Table[Plot[Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, i}], {x, -1, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {-4, 8}}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
   PlotPoints -> 1000], {i, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

Automatically selected `PlotRange`s for plots inside `Table` are

```
PlotRange /@ Table[Plot[Product[1/(1 - 1/Prime[n]^x), {n, 1, i}], {x, -1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black}, PlotPoints -> 1000], {i, 1, 2}]
```

> {{{-1., 10.}, {0.474519, 1.88074}}, {{-1., 10.}, {0.5, 3.87514}}}

so these plots are clipped at `1.88074` and `3.87514`. Providing explicit `PlotRange`s for the two `Plot`s inside `Table` prevents this clipping.